# Correlation between sentiment opinions of articles and sentiment of tweets. Comment on appropriate method

Tags: multilevel-analysis, sentiment-analysis

I want to measure a set of hashtags on twitter, and see if peoples sentiment on a set of hashtags is affected by the sentiment of newspaper articles that they retweet. What would be the best way to achieve this?

My approach was to record the tweets of users that use a set of hashtags. Any article that they retweet, measure that sentiment. For a given amount of time, measure the overall sentiment of related future tweets to compare.  Do this for a month for a statistically significant amount of users. The results would be obtained by a multi level regression.

Does this sound like a good approach? Does anyone have any good ideas as to any other ways to do this?

Comment: I think that is a good approach, at least in principle. I would be concerned, however, with the validity of the conclusions I'll obtain (mostly related to the problem that people who tweet about a topic are far from a random sample of the overall population) But if your conclusions will be restricted to the Twitter world, then your procedure is OK

Comment: You seem to assume that sentiment analysis reflects how people feel, and your hypothesis seems to be that tweeting negative news makes you unhappy. That won't just work. If Donald Trump tweets "so sad", he is likely feeling angry. Plus, you assume independence of Tweets, which clearly is wrong. I may be tweeting 20 tweets on the same sad story. So you likely measure topic persistence.